# How to implement multiple threadsafe read/write locks (ConcurrentHashmap)

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I have an application which reads and writes a number of files. The aim is to prevent a specific file from being read or written while it is being written by another thread. I do not want to lock the reading and writing of all files while a single file is being written as this causes unnecessary locking.

To try and achieve this I am using a concurrentHashMap in conjunction with a synchonized block, but if there is a better solution I am open to it.

Here is the rough code.

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, String> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();


private void createCache(String templatePath, String cachePath){

//get template 
String temp = getTemplate(templatePath);

String myRand = randomString();
lockMap.put(cachePath,myRand);

// save cache file
  try {
    // ** is  lockMap.get(cachePath) still threadsafe if another thread has changed the row's value?
    synchronized ( lockMap.get(cachePath) ){
      Files.write(Paths.get(cachePath),temp.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
  } finally {
    // remove lock if not locked by another thread in the meantime
    lockMap.remove(cachePath, myRand);
  }

}


private String getCache(String cachePath){

 String output = null;

  //only lock if this specific file is being written at the moment
  if ( lockMap.contains(cachePath) ){
        synchronized ( lockMap.get(cachePath) ){
            output = getFile(cachePath);
        }
    } else {
        output = getFile(cachePath);
    }

  return output;

}

// main event        
private String cacheToString (String templatePath, String cachePath){

  File cache = new File(cachePath);

  if ( !cache.exists() ){
    createCache(templatePath, cachePath)
  }

  return getCache(cachePath);

}
```

The problem I have is that although the thread will only remove the lock for the requested file if it's unchanged by another thread, it's still possible for another thread to update the value in the lockMap for this entry - if this happens will the synchronisation fail?

Comment: When you lock an object, you lock that object and the fact it came from a map or anywhere doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW Your put is not thread safe so multiple threads can put and lock different objects for the same key. Locking on a String works but should be highly discouraged.

Comment: @PeterLawrey does that mean that synchronized block will not work cross thread because the object could be updated by another thread? If so how I can I get around this?

Comment: A simpler approach is to write to a random file name and rename it after.  That way it is thread safe and you won't be writing to the same file with multiple threads.

Comment: @PeterLawrey wouldn't I still have synchonization issues as I was renaming the file? (and thank you for your comments!)

Comment: if you rename two files to the same file, the last one is kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a new temporary file each time and rename it when finished. Renaming is atomic.

```
// a unique counter across restarts
final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()*1000);

private void createCache(String templatePath, String cachePath) {
    //get template
    String temp = getTemplate(templatePath);

    Path path = Paths.get(cachePath);
    Path tmpPath = Paths.get(path.getParent().toString(), counter.getAndIncrement() + ".tmp");
    // save cache file
    Files.write(tmpPath, temp.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Files.move(tmpPath, path, ATOMIC_MOVE, REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

If multiple threads try to write to the same file, the last one to perform a `move` wins.

Comment: This looks pretty awesome, using this method I assume I can also remove all mention of locking/synchronization from getCache (my read method) - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it uses the OS to worry about thread safety of the move operation.

Comment: I've implemented this and it is better in every way; more throughput, less cpu usage, simpler code. Thanks, I would upvote, but I don't have the reputation yet.